# How to add a voltage control to this frequency dependent negative resistor circuit?

Tags: filter, negative-resistance

I would like to control the filter frequency with a control voltage. I assume that resistors R17,18,19 and 24 must be replaced with a adequate sub circuit. Could someone advice me where should I start to look?

[image]

Comment: Look for voltage controlled filters (as used in analogue synthesizers).

Comment: I see a 7-pole L-C (R-FDNR) lowpass with an additional RC- stage. What do you want to "control"? The passband edge - without touching the filter characteristic?

Comment: I want to control the cut-off frequency of the LPF. Thanks.

Comment: Jerzy, Have you considered a switched-capacitor type filter? https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/analog-filters/MAX291.html. If you *must* control it with a voltage, its clock frequency could be generated with a voltage or current variable oscillator (even a 555 would work).